# how to extract words from each row csv file in python?

Tags: python, csv

I have a very large `.csv` file (1065 row x 1 column). Each row has sentences. I want to pick up several important words from my wordlist (.csv file) in each row and then make data term frequency for each row.

Comment: Have you looked into or tried the csv module? https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: If it only has one column is it really a csv file?

Comment: Can you provide a sample ? few lines of the files, set of words to look for and desired output.

Comment: Please provide a sample of your input, the desired output, and the Python code you have tried. Please also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I have just tried to put down something, hopefully this will help you. It could be done more efficiently probably, but it does the job.

Example of input file

```
bla bla bla. bla! bla bla apple!, :banana. apple!!!
banana bla bla, apple and banana
peach 12345 bla bla peach and banana, peach, banana! :apple
```

Code

```
# Your inputs
list_words = ['apple', 'banana','peach']
filename = 'example.txt'

# Set of characters to remove to tokenize the file's line
rm = ",:;?/-!."

# Read through the file per each line and do the math
with open(filename,'r') as fin:
    for count_line, line in enumerate(fin,1):
        clean_line = filter(lambda x: not (x in rm), line)
        # To hold the counts of each word
        words_frequency = {key: 0 for key in list_words}
        for w in clean_line.split():
            if w in list_words:
                words_frequency[w] += 1
        print 'Line', count_line,':', words_frequen
```

Output:

```
Line 1 : {'apple': 2, 'peach': 0, 'banana': 1}
Line 2 : {'apple': 1, 'peach': 0, 'banana': 2}
Line 3 : {'apple': 1, 'peach': 3, 'banana': 2}
```